# How to render html pages from another docker container using Flask?

Tags: docker, flask, docker-compose

I have 2 docker containers:

1. First one is an execution of the pipeline: after some transformation, html pages are saved in the evaluation and validation folders. Here is the folder structure of the container:

- training

  - metadata

    - evaluation

      - 1

        - eval.html
      - 2

        - eval.html
    - validation

      - 1

        - basic_test_test.html
        - basic_test_train.html
      - 2

        - basic_test_test.html
        - basic_test_train.html

2. Second container is a Flask webapp, which should render html pages from the first container. Basically, webapp should access evaluation and validation folder in the first container and take html pages and render them.

when I use link: http://localhost:5002/validation/1/basic_test_train

I got an error: `jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: 1/basic_test_train.html`

Question is: how can I render html pages from webapp docker container using access to folder from the first container (pipeline)?

Comment: A Docker container has an isolated filesystem, and one container can't see files in another.  How often does the pipeline execution happen?  Would it be reasonable to run it as part of an image build, or even before?

Comment: @DavidMaze  pipeline execution happens once per month and in general I don't have preferences about visualization of html pages. I am relatively new to Docker that's why I don't have a lot of ideas. Do you have suggestions?

Comment: @DavidMaze I think I made a mistake in terminology. Basically I have one docker container, which consists of 2 images. First one is a pipeline image (execution of the pipeline) and second one is a small Flask webapp, which renders html pages from pipeline image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Docker container has an isolated filesystem, and it can't see files on the host or other containers.  You somehow need to get the files you're serving into the container filesystem.

You note in a comment:

> pipeline execution happens once per month

That's fairly infrequent, and some of your library dependencies are probably updating faster than this.  (And totally reasonable, particularly if the pipeline execution takes the better part of a day to run to do some heavy-weight large-scale machine learning.)

What I would do here is build these files into your Flask application image.

Separately from the image build, run the training pipeline somewhere.  It sounds like a little more of a batch job so I might not run it via Compose.  Possibly you can run it without Docker at all.  Maybe you're uploading its results to a central server, and you can use `curl` and `tar` to retrieve them.  I'll assert that the files exist in the `./training` directory on the local system.

Now in your Dockerfile, you need to `COPY` those files into the image.  With the filesystem layout you've shown, the Dockerfile needs to be in the directory above both `training` and `training_webapp`.  This can otherwise mostly look like any other Python Dockerfile

```bash
FROM python:3.10-slim
WORKDIR /app
COPY training_webapp/requirements.txt ./
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY training_webapp/ ./

# Copy in the externally-produced training data
COPY training/ /training/

EXPOSE 5000
CMD ["./webapp.py"]
```

In your Compose file, you don't need a separate container to run the pipeline (you've already run it offline and built its results into the image).  You do need to make sure you specify the parent directory as the `build:` context directory.  You do not need `volumes:` to inject the webapp code into the container since it's also part of the image.

```yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
  webapp:
    build: .  # not ./training_webapp
    ports:
      - 5002:5000
    # no volumes:, nothing to depends_on:
```

It's worth noting that the `volumes:` in the `pipeline:` service in the original question would cause the pipeline's output to be written to the corresponding directories on the host system, so this could be a way to re-run the pipeline as needed.  You could use a separate Compose file to hold this, or use Compose [profiles](https://docs.docker.com/compose/profiles/) to avoid running the pipeline in day-to-day use.